Comparing Regularized Logistic Regression and XGBoost
Do you know any useful metric which allows to compare XGBoost and regularized logistic regression? I am looking for something that punishes the model complexity like in AIC / BIC or somehow gives insight to the tradeoff when applying XGBoost. Prediction performance is of course better when applying XGBoost, since there is a lot of optimization going on, on top of GBDT. I think that is not really taking into account the additional complexity which is required compared to a logistic regression.

Use clean train/test splits. And ideally work with a strictly consistent loss function, e.g., log loss.
